# Problem with the bluetooth connection of the Relay - RxAndroidBle

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java2, rxandroidble

I speak english a little bit sorry. I need your help because I have invested many hours, and I can not finish the last detail: _ (

I have to connect a mobile phone with bluetooth LE to a relay, to open or close the door. Provide with native Bluetooth and with sockets, but there was no way to do anything that worked. After researching a lot, I found the RxAndroidBle library and got the first results.

The problem is that I'm not used to programming with the reactive paradigm and I really do not know what I'm doing. I pass the code and the steps that follow, to see if something escapes me.

Steps:

1. Connect directly by known MAC address to device
2. Send opening hexadecimal command
3. In successful case, execute closing command with DELAY

```
    private void SendCommandRele(String enable, String disable, int time) {

        bleDevice = rxBleClient.getBleDevice("BB:A0:56:06:0A:0A");
        byte[] data = hexStringToByteArray (enable);
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

        connectionDisposable = bleDevice.establishConnection(false)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMapSingle(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(uuid, data))
            .doOnError(error -> errorConnection())
            .doOnComplete(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    CloseDevice(disable);
                }
            })
            //.repeat(3)
            .retryWhen(io.reactivex.Observable::cache)
            .doAfterNext(next -> CloseDevice(disable))
            //.take(1)
            .subscribe(
                well -> {
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                CloseDevice(disable);
                            }
                        },
                        time
                    );
                },
                failed -> Log.e("E","Error: ")
            );

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        //connectionDisposable.dispose();
    }

--

    private void CloseDevice(String disable) {
        bleDevice = rxBleClient.getBleDevice("BB:A0:56:06:0A:0A");
        byte[] data = hexStringToByteArray (disable);

        connectionDisposable = bleDevice.establishConnection(false)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMapSingle(rxBleConnection -> 
                rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000ffe1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"), data)
            )
            .doOnError(error -> {errorConnection();})
            //.repeat(3)
            //.retry(3)
            .take(1)
            .subscribe(
            );

        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

#### Actual results:

In general, the results I have are quite positive since sometimes it works, but sometimes it does not. A rath, works 10 times in a row, and the other does not work at all. Of course I need a stable connection.

#### Expected results:

correct work

Answer (score 0):

I found this errors:
- Task COMMON_BROADCAST_MESSAGE_RECIVED failed or timed out. Client disconnecting.
- bta_gattc_mark_bg_conn unable to find the bg connection mask for: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX